# how to set/use env variable in github actions?

Tags: environment-variables, github-actions

I would like to use path location in several steps in github action. I tried to follow ["DAY_OF_WEEK"](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#about-environment-variables=) example, but my test failed:

```
name: env_test

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

env:
  ILOC: d:/a/destination/
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup Instalation Location
      shell: cmd
      run: |
        echo "just iloc"      
        echo "${ILOC}"
        echo "env"
        echo env.ILOC
        mkdir "${ILOC}"
```

Here is relevant part of log:

```
Run echo "just iloc"      
  echo "just iloc"      
  echo "${ILOC}"
  echo "env"
  echo env.ILOC
  mkdir "${ILOC}"
  shell: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.EXE /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "{0}""
  env:
    ILOC: d:/a/local
"just iloc"      
"${ILOC}"
"env"
env.ILOC
'#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

So how to properly set GA global variable?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are properly setting it, only the way its accessed needs attention:

```
  1 name: learn_to_use_actions
  2 
  3 on:
  4   push
  5 
  6 env:
  7   MYVAR:  d:/a/destination/
  8 jobs:
  9   learn:
 10     name: use env
 11     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
 12     steps:
 13       - name: print env
 14         if: ${{ env.MYVAR == 'TEST' }}
 15         run: |
 16           echo "the var was detected to be test = " $MYVAR
 17 
 18       - name: other print env
 19         if: ${{ env.MYVAR != 'TEST' }}
 20         run: |
 21           echo  "the var was NOT detected to be test = " $MYVAR
```

when using inside a conditional, the whole test has to be escaped like:

```
 ${{ env.MYVAR != 'TEST' }}
```

when using in a command, it looks like like a nix env var like:

```
echo  "the var was detected to be test = " $MYVAR
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Finally I found out that with `runs-on: windows-latest` works only version `echo  "the var was detected to be test = " ${{env.MYVAR}}`

Comment: haha totally missed that you were using windows